# Less styling not being applied if components are called from another component in Ant design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to apply a global `border-radius: 0px` to my web application which uses Ant Design. So far, most of the components seem to adhere to the less styling applied (as shown in the code snippet below).

However, for some reason the `Input` component from `antd` does not seem to respect this.

**BasicInput.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'antd';

interface BasicInputProps {}

export const BasicInput: React.FC<BasicInputProps> = ({}) => {
  return <Input />; // Return the ant design component untouched.
};
```

**LargeButton.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { PG } from '../typography/PG';

interface LargeButtonProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
  icon: string;
  type?:
    | 'link'
    | 'default'
    | 'ghost'
    | 'primary'
    | 'dashed'
    | 'danger'
    | undefined;
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent) => void;
}

export const LargeButton: React.FC<LargeButtonProps> = ({
  children,
  type,
  icon,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Button type={type} size='large' icon={icon} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

**input.stories.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BasicInput } from './BasicInput';
import { LargeButton } from '../buttons/LargeButton';
import { Spacer, Padding } from '../../config/styledConstants';

export default {
  title: 'Input'
};

export const sampleInput = () => (
  <Padding>
    <LargeButton></LargeButton>
    <BasicInput placeholder='Oh peach pit where had the hours gone...' />
  </Padding>
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

{
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'less-loader',

            options: {
              modifyVars: {
                '@border-radius-base': '0px',
                '@border-radius-sm': '0px',
                '@font-family': 'Oswald, sans-serif',
                '@black': '#1B2021',
                '@white': '#F2F2F2'
              },
              javascriptEnabled: true
            }
          }
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
      }
...
```

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot from storybook, the button has no border radius while the input component still has a radius. This is despite having having override the less styling.

Strangely, if I directly import the core component into the stories, the border radius disappears:

**Workaround by directly importing into stories**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BasicInput } from './BasicInput';
import { Input } from 'antd'; // IMPORT DIRECTLY.
import { Spacer, Padding } from '../../config/styledConstants';

export default {
  title: 'Input'
};

export const sampleInput = () => (
  <Padding>
    <Input /> // THIS WORKS.
  </Padding>
);
```

Is there a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's just input that does not depend upon the border-radius. try to manually override that by CSS styling.

Comment: What is your folders tree? Which webpack.config.js is this